# How can i have a gridview or details view in a popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my design

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial"
            Font-Size="11pt" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAll" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ID" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'
                            runat="server" />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="deleteRec" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblFileName1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="img" runat="Server" CommandName="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/pen.png" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEdit" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none"
            Width="1000px">
            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="File Data"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <table align="center" width="1000px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="RecordTypeCode"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRec" runat="server" Text="Content"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFileHeader" runat="server" Text="FileHeader"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtCustomerID" Width="500px" MaxLength="5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBatchHeader" runat="server" Text="BatchHeader"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtBatch" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="EntryDetail"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtEntry" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return Hidepopup()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false" PopupControlID="pnlAddEdit"
            TargetControlID="lnkFake" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have taken some text boxes inside a panel when a pop-up opens but instead of that i need a gridview to be there as i have to display the content of a large file

This is my data

```
 101 111100022 5104885671104200936A094101CapitalOne                           MudiamInc        
5220MudiamInc                           A510488567CCDITServices000000110422   1111100020000001
622968765348545646565        00004000001007           rajeshk                 1111100020000001
62297877654775676546546      00002888891007           rajeshk                 1111100020000002
82200000020194754188000000000000000000688889A510488567                         111100020000001
5220MudiamInc                           A510488567CCDITServices000000110422   1111100020000002
62212345678034354465677      00000864451005           swethau                 1111100020000003
62212345678087664534543      00000559841011           swathiK                 1111100020000004
62212345678097867546435      00000579351012           lavanyaK                1111100020000005
6221234567806754654435435    00000846761013           AnithaN                 1111100020000006
82200000040049382712000000000000000000285040A510488567                         111100020000002
9000002000001000000060244136900000000000000000071739300
```

This i have to show sequentially in an order as

```
  RecordTyecode           Content

   FileHeader          Starting line to be here
   BatchHeader        Line that come's with 5(First come line)
   EntryDetail        Number of 6 line has to be added on by one
   BatchControl       line that starts with 8 has to be here
```

Again if i have line starts with `5` after `8` that has to be appended like above sequence

Can any give me an idea to add this dynamically a little tricky to understand ask if any information required

This was done in `winforms` exact i need in web too

[image]

Comment: `How can i have a gridview or details view in a popup` You can use [jQuery FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) Then load your page using iFrame instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in a simple way i get this answer

Declared a hash table

```
   static Hashtable rectype = new Hashtable();
```

In page load i add the following

```
if (rectype != null)
{
    rectype.Add("1", "File Header");
    rectype.Add("5", "Batch Header");
    rectype.Add("6", "Entry Detail");
    rectype.Add("7", "Addenda Record");
    rectype.Add("8", "Batch Control");
    rectype.Add("9", "File Control");
}
```

Here is my code when user clicks on Image button

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = 0;
    string strLine = string.Empty;
    string[] lines = null;
    if (e.CommandName == "Image")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
        Label l = (Label)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Label1");
        id = Convert.ToInt16(l.Text);

        string selectSQL = "Select File_Data from tblachmaster WHERE Id IN (" + id + ")";

        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(selectSQL);
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        DataTable dt1 = GetData1(cmd1);
        if (dt1 != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt1.Rows[i]["File_Data"];
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n");
                strLine = convertArrayToString(lines);
            }
        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("RecordTypeCode", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));
        foreach (string strcontent in lines)
        {
            if (strcontent != string.Empty)
                table.Rows.Add(rectype[(strcontent.Substring(0, 1))], strcontent);


        }
        dynamicGridView.DataSource = table;
        dynamicGridView.DataBind();
        popup.Show();

    }
}
```

This works well for me and here is my output after clicking on Image button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax pop up control similar to this - 
    http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=2861497

Comment: but i would like to add dynamical rows and columns in the popup gridview

Comment: @Dorababu - Yeah not a problem at run time you would pass columns and data to add in grid view right ?

Comment: Tech : But i would like to add the content exactly as per the posted image that's what i am thinking